# "Send email with option" not working properly in Microsoft power automate

Tags: sharepoint, automation, power-automate

I have an excel online available on sharepoint which i am using for the power automate cloud flow.
This file contains more than 100 records where i want to send an email to customers for all the records & get a response from customer in the form of "Accept/Reject".

I tried doing this by using "send email with option" but unable to do so as my flow is getting terminated **after sending 25-30 emails per run**.

My flow has following steps:

[image]

How to send all the emails at one go?

[image]

Comment: Why is it terminating?  What error are you getting?  Can you please update your question to show the error?

Comment: After 10 minutes the flow shows "Run timed out error', where as it sends only 25 emails per run. Even though the file has more than 100 line items.

Comment: I'd back off your loop so that the parallelism is only processing 5 (or maybe a bit less) emails at a time.  Change it in the `Apply to each` step in the settings.

Comment: Maybe try something 4 or less ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling-limits#outlook-service-limits

Comment: I tried changing "Apple to each" setting. The highest degree of Parallelism available is 50 only, can i set the Parallelism to a variable number which can be more than 50.

Comment: No, but don't set to the max, that's the opposite of what I'm suggesting.  Set it to 3 or 4 and see how it goes.

Comment: It sends an exact number of mails which has been set as a limit to the degree of Parallelism. If is set it to 3 then it sends only 3 mails, if i set it to 50 then it sends 50 mails.

Comment: Wow, that’s interesting because that’s not the purposes of that setting. Can you update your question to show the inside of the apply to each step?

Comment: I have updated a link for the image to show the inside of the apply to each step.